# XMPP Components Subscription to PubSub nodes

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, subscription

I am looking to implement XMPP Components and subscribe them to a PubSub node. The  [XEP-0060](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html) specification talks about how XMPP Entities can subscribe to a node but not how XMPP components can be subscribed to pubsub nodes.

How to achieve this task or any library available that can help?

I am not using an open source XMPP Server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell nothing prevents components, usually bare JIDs with just a Domainpart, from subscribing to PubSub nodes. If it actually works depends on the PubSub service's implementation.